# Having issues with List in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have this class:

```
public class Attributes {


    List text = new ArrayList();

    List angle = new ArrayList();

    public Attributes() {

    }

    public int getHowManyNodes() {

        int howMany = 0;

        howMany += text.isEmpty() ? 0 : text.size();
        howMany += angle.isEmpty() ? 0 : angle.size();

        return howMany;
    }

}
```

And when I do:

```
Attributes attributes = new Attributes();
System.out.print(attributes.getHowManyNodes());
```

It gives **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException**

Weirdly tho, it only gives an error on *"angle.isEmpty()"* not on *"text.isEmpty()"*

Why does it say it is null when I initialize it with:

```
List angle = new ArrayList();
```

**Edit1:**

```
Full error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at projectmerger1.Attributes.getHowManyNodes(Attributes.java:55)
    at projectmerger1.Project.listGameVariables(Project.java:235)
    at projectmerger1.ProjectMerger1.main(ProjectMerger1.java:289)
Java Result: 1
```

Minor edit:

Line 55 in Attributes Class is

`howMany += angle.isEmpty() ? 0 : angle.size();`

**Edit2:**

```
    public class Project {

        Game game;

        public void listGameVariables() {

            System.out.print(game.attributes.getHowManyNodes());

        }

}

public class Game {

    Attributes attributes = new Attributes();
}
```

This is my whole setup.

Comment: This is not possible (with the code you provided)

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) along with the full text of the error?

Comment: try initialize ArrayList in the constructor

Comment: Can we see the entire stack trace?

Comment: @shan, it doesn't matter. @can berk, is there a possibility that you have another method which gets invoked prior to `getHowManyNodes()` which assigns it `null`?

Comment: Maybe in the real code some other variable named `angle` hides the list?

Comment: I agree with @ZouZou unless some weird import is confusing us.

Comment: Please specify the type when creating arraylists, it's just good practice. So specify something in these brackets <Type>.

Comment: A SSCCE is not that easy since I'm using this as a part of XML reading with XStream, so I couldn't menage to trim enough. And I tried initializing in the constructor, still the same output. And I'm not sure what you mean by _stack trace_ but I'll post the full error in question now.

Comment: We can't answer yet. The code you provided will **never** cause the `NullPointerException` you are seeing.

Comment: Can you please show us your main and listGameVariables

Comment: Stacktrace is the full text of the message you provided: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Which statement is line 55 in your `Attributes` class?

Comment: There is simply no way the code you've provided would throw NullPointerException. There has to be some other code that is causing the list to be null.

Comment: After you instantiate angle, put a block of code on the next line.  `{System.out.println(angle))}`.  What happens?

Comment: Maybe your code is not synchronized with your class files. Try to clean (delete class files) and compile again.

Comment: Try changing the definition of the lists to make them `final`; it could be that XStream is replacing the initialised values.

Comment: Make your two list fields private, and see what code breaks.  This might show you if another method is changing these fields to null.  (They should be private in the first place.)

Comment: Can you show us what the listGameVariables method is doing? Or maybe paste the listGameVariables method in the question?

Comment: Where should I check to find where this fails? @his would another _angle_ in another class mass this up? If yes, would adding "this." to the beginning of vars change that?

Comment: @canberk yes, another angle would mess it up.

Comment: Yes, change your reference in the method to `text` and `angle` to `this.text` and `this.angle`.

Comment: In another class probably not. Somehow it has to be in scope at that moment.

Comment: Hurra !!!!! Game is `null`.

Comment: @ZouZou if game is null it can't fail in Attributes.java:55

Comment: @ZouZou but I can reach _text.size()_ but not _angle.size()_

Comment: @canberk You are not telling us the truth. You forgot something important or you are lying.

Comment: Please copy us your imports.

Comment: @user270349 You're right. But game is `null`, so the OP should correct this too.

Comment: @canberk show us your main method.

Comment: I haven't get the exception.. Working fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments (and your code) one (or both) of your List(s) must be null. I would add a null check like this

```
howMany += text == null ? 0 : text.size();
howMany += angle == null ? 0 : angle.size();
```

It's possible you have another method that is "nulling" those fields.

Comment: what'd be the point of isEmpty check? the size would be 0 anyway.

Comment: @eis Good catch! Copied and pasted from OP's question.

Comment: works like a charm thanks! @eis to be honest I was trying to get rid of the error and "text == null" didn't come to my mind.

Comment: This still bothers me, because even though this is what you should do, how angle could have been null in the first place is still not known.  There's a bug in your code.

Comment: @canberk This is an alternative to the error, but i'm not sure this the way to go. You have investigate why you have this NPE.

Comment: @TJamesBoone yeah I'll try to figure out for some time and I'll post an answer of mine as soon as I find it.

Answer (score 1):

I've compiled and run this code, it prints out 0 with no NullPointerException. There is no way to get this error with the code you provided.

```
public class Attributes {


    List text = new ArrayList();

    List angle = new ArrayList();

    public Attributes() {

    }

    public int getHowManyNodes() {

        int howMany = 0;

        howMany += text.isEmpty() ? 0 : text.size();
        howMany += angle.isEmpty() ? 0 : angle.size();

        return howMany;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Attributes attributes = new Attributes();
        System.out.print(attributes.getHowManyNodes());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a BreakPoint in the first source code line of your `getHowManyNodes()` method, start your program in debug mode and try to figure out where the error comes from by using the short cut keys (Eclipse) `F5` -> StepInto and `F6` -> StepOver. Your source provided looks fine and shouldn't cause any problems. By debugging your application via Eclipse or any other IDE, you should easily find such errors.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way that this could be happening is if:

1. angle is being accessed somewhere else and set to null before you call getHowManyNodes().
2. angle is being "shadowed" by another variable of the same name that you are not showing in your code example.

Ways to debug this:

1. Make your variables private and final, and see what code they break so you can see if they're being set to null elsewhere.
2. Put System.out.println(angle) in a block of code under your instantiation of angle, and also in your constructor.

Ways to avoid this bug in the future:

1. Encapsulate your variables.
2. Make your methods null-safe.